# error with composer autoload installing phpspreadsheet

Tags: phpspreadsheet

I've never used composer before, so I'm not sure what this error means or what I need to do.  But I am trying to use PHPSpreadsheet to be able to convert excel files into php for adding information to a database.

> Uncaught Exception: Composer autoloader could not be found. Install
>   dependencies with `composer install` and try again.

Can anyone tell me what I need to do to get this system working.

Running cPanel with PHP7 EasyApache4

I do have root access to dedicated server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you haven't installed the packages via composer.

You have to create a file named "composer.json" on the root of your project.

it should be something like this:

```
{
    "require": {
        "phpmailer/phpmailer":"5.2.22",
        "slim/slim":"2.0",
        "rain/raintpl":"3.0.0",
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "ProjectName\\": "vendor\\projectPackage\\php-classes\\src"
        }
    }
}
```

After that you should run the command "composer install" on you git bash and it will download your dependencies and create an autoload for you.